# Power BI - £ sign changes to # in text field

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm creating some reports in Power BI. The data is stored on a SQL server and contains a Unit column with different units consisting of text and/or symbols. I have a problem with the £ sign, which is being converted by Power BI into a #.

How do I get Power BI to stop doing this? I can't see anything in the settings allowing me to change to UK English.

I'm getting around this by using Power Query to replace the # with a £. I could create a new column and use a substitute formula, but either solution isn't ideal in the long term, because 1/ the hashtag may be used for something else in the future and 2/ data comes from multiple sources and it will require additional work to ensure that the correct text is used in the report.

Answer (score 0):

Go to data view in powerbi desktop.

[image]

Select the column you need to add currency. And from the above tabs click your currency.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have something slightly different. The format is set to Text and I can't change it through the drop down. The rest is greyed out and unavailable.

Comment: So you're saying your column is not currency, it's a single char? No Numbers? Because if it is currency you choose currency and then in the data model set a format string. If it's only text, but a weird character, verify you are using the right encoding. SQL can have different collations per server, per table,